# Cornerstone3D html image not found

Tags: html, node.js, cornerstone

I want to modify the html of the html loaded in cornerstone3d, this html is in

```
/var/lib/cornerstone3D/utils/ExampleRunner/template.html
```

I can modify it, but I want to add an image to it, so I added a folder img in the same route

and then `<img src="../img/image.png"></img>`

I tried also with img/image.png

But when I start the project with **yarn run example tutorial** in /var/lib/cornerstone3D the image is not being displayed.

I also tried adding the folder with the image there but also does not work.

If I double click the html then the image displays but I want to access to localhost:3000 and in that site display the image.

It's driving me nuts and I just want to simply get the image from the folder.

can somebody tell me how to do this please?